# How to put a different button inside a list of chips in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hi! I want to put a button to add more chip widget in a list of chip widgets. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActionChip` on `Wrap`

```dart
Wrap(
    children: [
      ActionChip(
        label: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      ActionChip(...,
    ],
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I write code for adding new button dynamically as you asked:

[image]

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MainApplication());

class MainApplication extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> _selectedChips = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Home Page'),
        ),
        body: CategoryPage(
          selectedList: _selectedChips,
        ));
  }
}

class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> selectedList;

  CategoryPage({this.selectedList = const []});

  @override
  _CategoryPageState createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {
  List<String> data = ['Add', 'Food', 'Entertainment', 'Other', 'Clear'];

  List<String> selectedList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedList = widget.selectedList;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Wrap(
        spacing: 6,
        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        children: data.map(
          (dataItem) {
            return FilterChip(
              label: Text(dataItem),
              selected: selectedList.contains(dataItem),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              selectedColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 3,
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: !selectedList.contains(dataItem)
                    ? Colors.white
                    : Colors.black,
              ),
              onSelected: (bool selected) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    if (dataItem == 'Add') {
                      addElement(dataItem: dataItem, newItem: "item New");
                    }
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void addElement({String? dataItem, String? newItem}) {
    setState(() => data.insert(data.indexOf(dataItem!) + 1, newItem!));
  }
}
```